# Change the codeigniter view contents without reload

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I have created an email utility which shows the email-ids from which email is received their subject line and date. Every email id has a checkbox alongside it. Whichever checkbox is clicked the email is sent to that email id. My problem is that i want to display "message sent successful" or error message on the same page without reload.

I think, it is possible with ajax, but I don't know how. Here is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('accessmail/sendmail'); ?>
    <div>   
            //here I display my emails
            <div>
        <div class="table_wrap1">
                <div>Subject:</div>
                <div><input type="text" required="required" id="subject" name="subject"></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="table_wrap1">       
                <div>Email:</div>
                <div><input type="email" id="replyto" name="replyto"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="txteditor">
                <textarea name="textarea">  
                </textarea>
                <button name="submit" value="process" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>

        <?php } ?> 

    </div>
</form>
```

And my controller name is "accessmail", method name is "send mail":

```
public function sendmail()
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $count=$this->input->post('mailcount'); 
    $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
    $msg = $this->input->post('textarea');
    $replyto = $this->input->post('replyto');
    //variable for checking whether any email id is selected or not
    $status=0;
    //for sending email to checked email id's
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        // check whether the checkbox for a particular email id is checked or not
        if(!$this->input->post('emailid'.$i))
        {   

            continue;
        }
        else    
        {   
            //set the values for this email and send it
            $this->email->from('abc@abc.com', 'abc');
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($msg);
            $idtosend = $this->input->post('emailid'.$i);
            $this->email->to($idtosend);
            if ($this->email->send())
            {
                $status++;
            }
        }
    }
    //for sending email to email id provide in textbox
    if(!empty($replyto))
    {
        $this->email->from('abc@abc.com', 'Abc');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($msg);
        $this->email->to($replyto);
        if ($this->email->send())
        {
            $status++;
        }
    }
    if($status>0)
    {
          //this message should be displayed on the same page along with other contents of the page
        echo "Your message has been sent";
    }
    if($status==0)
    {
        //this message should be displayed on the same page along with other contents of the page
        echo "Select any Email-id first";
    }

}
```

my problem is the success message should be displayed on the same view preserving the contents of the page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just use an alert that pops up when clicking the checkbox. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Kees I don't want to use alert boxes, i want to use ajax to show messages like gmail do when message is sent successfully

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a typical Ajax thing. But unfortunately that's a bit too big to just deliver you the answer (or I am too lazy, but you would benefit the most out of it, by figuring this out yourself).
My suggestion is, that you learn jQuery and Ajax (if you don't know that already).

For your problem, you specifically want to send the mails to your PHP-Function sendmail() via Ajax. This function either returns a Success- or an Errormessage (with json_encode() around it, that's how I'd do it). The Ajax-function then displays the message.

This is neither tested nor should be the final solution... just a hint:

The PHP Function:

```
<?php
function sendmail()
{
  $mails = $_POST['mails'];
  $countEmails = count($mails);
  $success = 0;
  foreach ($mails as $mail) {
    // Check and send mails here
    if ($this->email->send()) {
      $success++;
    }
  }
  if ($success < $countEmails) {
    echo json_encode('One or more E-Mails were not sent');
    return;
  }
  echo json_encode('E-Mails successfully sent');
}
```

Ajax Function (don't forget to include jquery):

```
$('#id_of_your_send_mails_button').bind('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'path/to/sendmail',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      mails: $('#id_of_your_form').serialize();
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $('#id_of_your_status_div').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Again, this is just pseudocode-ish stuff, to get you to it, but you have to do the learning on your own.

Hope that helps a bit.

**EDIT**
You might also try:

```
$('#id_of_your_send_mails_button').bind('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'path/to/sendmail',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      name: $('#id_of_your_name_field').val(),
      email: $('#id_of_your_name_field').val() // and so forth
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $('#id_of_your_status_div').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Just make sure you use the CSRF/XSS prevention tools that Codeigniter has to offer otherwise you could find your self at the end of someone using your code maliciously.

Comment: The problem is if I use Ajax click function on submit button, i can't get form data in my controller using 'this->input->post('name')'